# How to create/add to an array of json objects from an already existing list (discord.py related)?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

Kind of hard to word the initial question.

I'm working with discord.py and I want to basically go through the entire list of members in my server and add their name along with a number as an object in a json file.

So it would be something like

```
for member in ctx.message.guild.members:

    *add member.name*
    *add skill level 0*
```

And the result in the json file would be

```
[{
   Name: Plzwork
   SkillLevel: 5
},
{
   Name: Blah
   SkillLevel: 5
},
```

and so on...
I've tried to look this up, but no straight answer in my opinion.

Also on the reverse, how do you iterate back through the now created json array and read the name as a string in python and the skill level as an int?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Do you know how to use Python dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like this

```
import json
memberList = []
for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
    memberList.append({'name': member.name, 'skillLevel': member.skillLevel})
print(json.dumps(memberList))
```

I don't know if that is the correct way to reference the member skillLevel. This is just a guideline.

An alternative one-liner using list comprehension would be like this

```
import json
result = json.dumps([{'name': x.name, 'skillLevel': x.skillLevel} for x in members])
print(result)
```

To iterate through the json, you would convert it from a json string to an object using

```
parsed = json.loads(result)
for member in parsed:
    print(member['name'] + " " + str(member['skillLevel']))
```

Again a one-liner using list comprehension is as follows

```
parsed = json.loads(result)
[print(member['name'] + " " + str(member['skillLevel'])) for member in parsed]
```

Comment: skill level is just a custom number i want to add to the json object. Its not a part of 'member'

Comment: Oh, then just replace member.skillLevel with whatever value you would like to use

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style..